# IOS: add imageview in a scrollview to have zoom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to set a UIImageView with a `UIImage` and put this imageview inside a `UIScrollView` to obtain a zoom of this image;
and I want this `UIImageView` and `UIScrollView` to fit in the rect at the center of the view...is it possible?

Comment: So you want the image to zoom with a pinch, but everything else in the scroll view to stay the same?

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible.  Have you tried anything at all?  Most of what you are describing can be done in the interface builder / storyboard

Answer (score 91, accepted):

1. Set your view controller up as a `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`
2. Draw your `UIScrollView` the size you want for the rectangle at the center of the view.  Set the max zoom in the inspector to something bigger than 1.  Like 4 or 10.
3. Right click on the scroll view and connect the delegate to your view controller.
4. Draw your `UIImageView` in the `UIScrollView` and set it up with whatever image you want.  Make it the same size as the `UIScrollView`.
5. Ctrl + drag form you `UIImageView` to the `.h` of your View controller to create an `IBOutlet` for the `UIImageView`, call it something clever like `imageView`.
6. Add this code:

   > ```
   > -(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   > {
   >     return self.imageView;
   > }
   > ```
7. Run the app and pinch and pan til your heart's content.

Comment: Can you make an example of this but programatically?

Comment: by far the simplest and most clear solution I have found

Comment: @Justin Paulson Can we restrict the zoomout to the image size. I don't want the user to zoom out from the image size. Can u pls help me?

Answer (score 29):

Download [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/2_Autoscroll_Classes_TapDetectingImageView_h.html)  and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TapDetectingView_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-3_Tiling_Classes_TapDetectingView_h-DontLinkElementID_21) files. You'll need them to handle touches.

Add to your view the scrollView delegate `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` and declare the outlets:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *imageScrollView;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

Import the downloaded file inside the screen and do:

```
#import "TapDetectingImageView.h"

#define ZOOM_STEP 2.0
@interface myView (UtilityMethods)
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end


@implementation myView
@synthesize imageScrollView, imageView;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Setting up the scrollView    
    imageScrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
    imageScrollView.delegate = self;
    imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //Setting up the imageView
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);

    //Adding the imageView to the scrollView as subView
    [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.bounds.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height);
    imageScrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;

    //UITapGestureRecognizer set up
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    //Adding gesture recognizer
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = 1.0;//This is the minimum scale, set it to whatever you want. 1.0 = default
    imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;
    imageScrollView.zoomScale = minimumScale;
    [imageScrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView sizeToFit];
    [imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];



}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGFloat offsetX = (imageScrollView.bounds.size.width > imageScrollView.contentSize.width)? 
    (imageScrollView.bounds.size.width - imageScrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = (imageScrollView.bounds.size.height > imageScrollView.contentSize.height)? 
    (imageScrollView.bounds.size.height - imageScrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageScrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX, 
                                   imageScrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.imageScrollView = nil;
    self.imageView = nil;
}



#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView;
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // zoom in
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;

    if (newScale > self.imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale){
        newScale = self.imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale;
        CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];

        [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];

    }
    else{

        newScale = self.imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale;
        CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];

        [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
    }
}


- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // two-finger tap zooms out
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. 
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}
```

Done!

Basically what this code do is to add the `imageView` as subview of the `imageScrollView`.

Then, it adds the `TapDetecting` class methods to the scrollView, in order to recognize the number of taps - the pinch the user do and add zoom functionalities.

You can set the `minimumScale` of the image, if you leave `1.0` the image should be displayed as-it-is (if you set it a little bit lower it's being scaled), and the `maximumZoomScale`, i suggest you to leave it to 4, it's fine!

Now, you can load images programmatically from there.

The last thing you have to do is to insert a `UIScrollView` inside your xib file and link it to `imageScrollView`. You'll have the image at the perfect center, you can double tap on it to zoom, pinch to zoom as you set up in code.

Comment: This is like a cooking recipe. The steps a right but you don't explain why he should do it this way. This would help him and others in the end more.

Comment: This is basically the code i'm using in my apps. I'm gonna explain

Comment: Don't get me wrong - the code is good, but the why is important too. Otherwise he will not know how to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Sure, and you're right! I just thought that the in-code comments were self-explanatory! Thanks for noticing me, though.

Comment: on double tap ,when zooming an image it scales as much as scrollview and goes out of screen .how to solve it?

Answer (score 8):

With Swift 4 and iOS 11, you can use one of the two following solutions in order to solve your problem.

---

## #1. Using insets

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let scrollView = ImageScrollView(image: UIImage(named: "image")!)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.frame = view.frame
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

}
```

*ImageScrollView.swift*

```
import UIKit

final class ImageScrollView: UIScrollView {

    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if frame.size != oldValue.size { setZoomScale() }
        }
    }

    required init(image: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        imageView.image = image
        imageView.sizeToFit()
        addSubview(imageView)
        contentSize = imageView.bounds.size

        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never // Adjust content according to safe area if necessary
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
        alwaysBounceVertical = true
        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Helper methods

    func setZoomScale() {
        let widthScale = frame.size.width / imageView.bounds.width
        let heightScale = frame.size.height / imageView.bounds.height
        let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        minimumZoomScale = minScale
        zoomScale = minScale
    }

}
```

```
extension ImageScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
        let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
        let verticalInset = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
        let horizontalInset = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalInset, left: horizontalInset, bottom: verticalInset, right: horizontalInset)
    }

}
```

---

## #2. Using Auto Layout

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let scrollView = ImageScrollView(image: UIImage(named: "image")!)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {        
        scrollView.setZoomScale()
    }

}
```

*ImageScrollView.swift*

```
import UIKit

final class ImageScrollView: UIScrollView {

    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    private var imageViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    private var imageViewLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    private var imageViewTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    private var imageViewTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

    required init(image: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        imageView.image = image
        imageView.sizeToFit()
        addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageViewLeadingConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor)
        imageViewTrailingConstraint = imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        imageViewTopConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        imageViewBottomConstraint = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageViewLeadingConstraint, imageViewTrailingConstraint, imageViewTopConstraint, imageViewBottomConstraint])

        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never // Adjust content according to safe area if necessary
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
        alwaysBounceVertical = true
        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Helper methods

    func setZoomScale() {
        let widthScale = frame.size.width / imageView.bounds.width
        let heightScale = frame.size.height / imageView.bounds.height
        let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        minimumZoomScale = minScale
        zoomScale = minScale
    }

}
```

```
extension ImageScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let yOffset = max(0, (bounds.size.height - imageView.frame.height) / 2)
        imageViewTopConstraint.constant = yOffset
        imageViewBottomConstraint.constant = yOffset

        let xOffset = max(0, (bounds.size.width - imageView.frame.width) / 2)
        imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xOffset
        imageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = xOffset

        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

---

Sources:

- [Github / ImageScrollView](https://github.com/imanoupetit/ImageScrollView)
- [raywenderlich.com / UIScrollView Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/159481/uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started)

Answer (score 3):

I have written an example application which also supports AutoLayout and Storyboards to demonstrate this behavior. I hope it saves everyone time trying to figure this out: http://rexstjohn.com/facebook-like-ios-photo-modal-gallery-swipe-gestures/.