# How to zoom an UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, zooming

I'm rendering `CGPDFPage` in `UIImageView` but not zooming how we can zoom if any know plz let me know

```
        PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfUrl);

        totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument);

        NSLog(@"total pages %i",totalPages);

        //struct CGPDFPage *page =CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);

        CGFloat width = 600.0;

        // Get the page
        CGPDFPageRef myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, i);


        // Changed this line for the line above which is a generic line
        //CGPDFPageRef page = [self getPage:page_number];

        CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);

        CGFloat pdfScale = width/pageRect.size.width;

        pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*pdfScale, pageRect.size.height*pdfScale);

        pageRect.origin = CGPointZero;


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // White BG
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
        CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        // ***********
        // Next 3 lines makes the rotations so that the page look in the right direction
        // ***********
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox, pageRect, 0, true));

        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, myPageRef);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        imageView= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out-in-ios

follow tap gesture and click on image

Answer (score 0):

You should add your `imageView` as subview of `UIScrollView`.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318845/ios-add-imageview-in-a-scrollview-to-have-zoom) describes how to zoom `UIImageView` inside `UIScrollView`:

1. Set your view controller up as a `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`
2. Draw your `UIScrollView` the size you want for the rectangle at the center of the view.  Set the max zoom in the inspector to something bigger than 1.  Like 4 or 10.
3. Right click on the scroll view and connect the delegate to your view controller.
4. Draw your `UIImageView` in the `UIScrollView` and set it up with whatever image you want.  Make it the same size as the `UIScrollView`.
5. Ctrl + drag form you `UIImageView` to the `.h` of your View controller to create an `IBOutlet` for the `UIImageView`, call it something clever like `imageView`.
6. Add this code:

   > ```
   > -(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   > {
   >     return self.imageView;
   > }
   > ```
7. Run the app and pinch and pan til your heart's content.

Comment: this method work for me but now how to zoom image in double tap

Comment: @Stela, you should implement it on your own. Here is exaple from Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomingByTouch/ZoomingByTouch.html. Or also you can use gesture recognizer.

Comment: already i have put this method and its work .. i have problem with double tap zoom

Answer (score -1):

Go with this

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{

    return self.imageView;

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;

    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;

    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280, 960);

    self.scrollView.delegate=self;

}
```

[Check Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html)

Another way is to implement UITapGestureRecognizer in your viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];       

    // target - what object is going to handle 
    // the gesture when it gets recognised
    // the argument for tap: is the gesture that caused this message to be sent
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = 
     [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  
                                             action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = 
     [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  
                                             action:@selector(tapTwice:)];

    tapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    //stops tapOnce from overriding tapTwice
    [tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice];

    // then need to add the gesture recogniser to a view 
    // - this will be the view that recognises the gesture  
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];

}
```

Basically this code is saying that when a UITabGesture is registered in self.view the method tapOnce or tapTwice will be called in self depending on if its a single or double tap. You therefore need to add these tap methods to your UIViewController:

```
- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //on a single  tap, call zoomToRect in UIScrollView
    [self.myScrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomInTo animated:NO];
}
- (void)tapTwice:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //on a double tap, call zoomToRect in UIScrollView
    [self.myScrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomOutTo animated:NO];
}
```

Hope that helps