# Zoom an image to a particular rect with animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a **UIImageView** in my app.I have added that inside a UIScrollView.Now when i tap on image then image is zoomed within the scrollview.So it X,Y is fixed but it is zoomed to a particular Rectangle.I want to zoom then also it's X & Y should be changed.After that then it should come back to it's orignal position.

Please tell how can i do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318845/ios-add-imageview-in-a-scrollview-to-have-zoom

Comment: It is not working now.Please tell more about this

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController

Please use JTSImageViewController and Your image touchevent generate and click event assign image  JTSImageViewController.