# ScrollView doesn't scroll in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an UIView and add an UIScrollView to it. Inside the scrollView is an UIImageView.
I want to zoom the image view by pressing a button. If the image view is zoomed you should be able to scroll but that's not working.

Currently I have that:

```
self.imageView = UIImageView()
self.imageView.image = image
self.imageView.frame = self.contentView.bounds

self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
self.scrollView.frame = self.contentView.bounds
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.imageView)

self.contentView.addSubview(self.scrollView)
```

and that:

```
@IBAction func zoomPicture() {
    if (scale <= 1.5) {
        scale = scale + 0.1
        scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
        scrollView.zoomScale = scale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.5
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.contentSize = contentView.bounds.size
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

my class also implements `UIScrollViewDelegate`and I set the delegate in the viewDidLoad() function. I have also added the `viewForZoomingInScrollView` function. The zoom works but I can't scroll.

Comment: Try to set `self.scrollView.contentSize` bigger than `self.contentView.bounds`

Comment: Nice, works! Does it matter how much the content size is bigger or not?

Comment: I think you answer in this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318845/ios-add-imageview-in-a-scrollview-to-have-zoom

Comment: @mafioso yes it matters and always try to set content size bigger, why this happens, is in answer i posted below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this issue you have to set `self.scrollView.contentSize` bigger than `self.contentView.bounds` so it get proper space to scroll.

replace this line

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size
```

to this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size*2 //or what ever size you want to set
```

Comment: do you also know why horizontal scrolling in landscape mode doesn't work?

Comment: have you enabled horizontal scroll from property ?

Comment: umm no I don't think so how would I do that?

Comment: you will get detailed about scroll view here https://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/
check this it will helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func zoomPicture() {
    if (scale <= 1.5) {
        scale = scale + 0.1
        scrollView.zoomScale = scale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.5
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        let size = contentView.bounds.size
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale)
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```