# Zoomable image in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I'm doing official iOS development tutorial from Apple. There is a task to make a zoomable image in a scrollView.
I believe that did it right. There is mistake, since I cant zoom image in.
The task is below in screenshots.

[Task part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twmYU.png)
[Task part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2dJv.png)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //set the scroll view's deligate to be the viewcontroller instance
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        viewForZooming(in: scrollView)
        }
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        updateZoomFor(size: view.bounds.size)
    }

    func updateZoomFor(size: CGSize) {
        let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
        let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
        let scale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale
        scrollView.zoomScale = scale
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318845/ios-add-imageview-in-a-scrollview-to-have-zoom. Follow instructions in this link. This is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. Too complicated code for me